# NoClassDefFoundError in jar but not in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to run a jar with dependencies. The application runs fine in Intellij but when I try to run the jar I get:

```
>> java -jar test-0.1.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atlassian/httpclient/apache/httpcomponents/DefaultHttpClient
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.createClient(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:53)
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:35)
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42)
        at Main.main(Main.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 4 more
```

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '2.9'
  distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-all.zip"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = "Main"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/'
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'test'
    version =  '0.1.0'

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Main'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

    compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-parent:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-api:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-plugin:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.atlassian.fugue:fugue-parent:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.atlassian.fugue:fugue:2.6.1'
}
```

I've also tried adding `transitive=true` to each compile clause to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [set CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

> The class path is the path that the Java runtime environment searches for classes and other resource files. The class search path (more commonly known by the shorter name, "class path") can be set using either the -classpath option when calling a JDK tool (the preferred method) or by setting the CLASSPATH environment variable. The -classpath option is preferred because you can set it individually for each application without affecting other applications and without other applications modifying its value.

**UPDATE:**

By default, Gradle doesn't copy dependencies to build folder or include it into the jar. There are three ways to solve the problem with dependencies:

1. Download them separately and put into the appropriate directory.
2. Use plugins to build *fat jar*. Something like [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).
3. Add to build.gradle task that copies dependencies into build folder.

For example

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/libs"
    from configurations.runtime
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanx. can you give a specific example? Now I'm doing `java -jar test-0.1.0.jar`. Should it be `java -classpath . -jar build\libs\test-0.1.0.jar` ?

Comment: Yes, if all dependencies jars are in the same folder.

Comment: My mistake! Try `java -classpath path\to\dependencies\* -jar build\libs\test-0.1.‌​0.jar`

Comment: I think I'm missing something? I don't know where are the dependencies. Shouldn't they be in the jar?

Comment: After trying option 3 I still couldn't get it to work. I've tries `java -jar build\libs\test-0.1.0.jar`, `java -classpath build\libs\ -jar build\libs\test-0.1.0.jar`, `java -classpath . -jar build\libs\test-0.1.0.jar`. All three resulted in the same bug

Comment: Hmm, `classpath` is ignored when `-jar` switch used... You can run jar with `java -cp build\libs\* Main` (don't forget asterisk) or you need to define classpath in the manifest.